# DataGridCell style based on DataGrid property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to add a style to the `DataGridCell` of a custom `DataGrid` which is based on property of that `DataGrid`. For example I want to have a DependencyProperty named VisualizeReadOnlyCells and if that property is set to True, I want the `DataGridCell` that is ReadOnly is drawn with gray background. And other similar things. As an workaround I have created two different styles for the `DataGridCell` and I assign those styles to the `CellStyle` property of the `DataGrid` in the `DataGrid` style definition. But with more properties the number of such styles will grow and the code would be very unmanageable.

My current solution is:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellNoVisualize" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    - style definition
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridCellVisualize" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="MyCustomDataGrid">
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellNoVisualize"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="VisualizeReadOnlyCells" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{Static Resource DataGridCellVisualize"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellUniversalStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    - style definition
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="MyParentDataGrid.VisualizeReadOnlyCells" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could use a `MultiDataTrigger` and bind to the `DataGridCell` and the parent `DataGrid`:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellUniversalStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding VisualizeReadOnlyCells, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyCustomDataGrid}}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: So simple? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting quite often an error in the Output window: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Test.Controls.MyCustomDataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VisualizeReadOnlyCells; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object'). Any clue why?